# How to split 1 key value into 2 keys values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript.  I have the following object:

```
let obj1 =
[{
  'id': 1,
  'longString': 'Joe - 2011-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
},
{
  'id': 2,
  'longString': 'Mary - 2010-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
}];
```

I want to split the `longString` key into 2 keys, and the value into 2 values.

Here is what I want to make:

```
let obj2 =
[{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Joe',
  'date': '2011-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
},
{
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'Mary',
  'date': '2010-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
}];
```

I've tried to do it in pieces, but I'm stuck with the first piece which is splitting the value of `longString`.

This works for string:

```
let v = 'Mary - 2010-04-23T18:25:23.511Z';
let w = v.split(' -', 1);
```

How do I make it work for an object? Or is there a totally different way to split property values? Also, do I need to write a loop to assign `obj1` to `obj2`?

Comment: FYI, JSON and JavaScript objects are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and split the `longString` for each object. Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the splits into `name` and `date` variables

```js
let obj1 =
[{
  'id': 1,
  'longString': 'Joe - 2011-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
},
{
  'id': 2,
  'longString': 'Mary - 2010-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
}];

const output = obj1.map(a => {
  let [name, date] = a.longString.split(" - ");
  return { id: a.id, name, date }
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `map` and `\s+-\s+` pattern to split. second parameter of split is to specify the number of element we want in output

```js
let obj1 =[{'id': 1,'longString': 'Joe - 2011-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'},{ 'id': 2, 'longString': 'Mary - 2010-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'}];

let op = obj1.map(({id, longString}) => {
  let [name, date] = longString.split(/\s+-\s+/,2)
  return { id, name, date }
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let obj1 = [{
    'id': 1,
    'longString': 'Joe - 2011-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'longString': 'Mary - 2010-04-23T18:25:23.511Z'
  }
];


const res = obj1.map(({
  id,
  longString
}) => ({
  id,
  name: longString.match(/\w+/)[0],
  date: longString.match(/\d+.*/)[0],
}))

console.log(res)
```